# Django is not saving form to datebase

Tags: python, django

I got the problem with form that is not saving to the datebase.

views.py

```
...
@login_required
def create_task(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateTaskForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('index')
    else:
        form = CreateTaskForm()
        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'tasks/task_form.html', context)
...
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Task


class CreateTaskForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = (
            'name',
            'end_date',
            'description',
        )
```

Is it the problem with a create_task view or CreateTaskForm?

Comment: Why are you passing the User instance to form to Task model? What is the error?

Comment: Besides the wrong instance that you pass, do you see any errors? If not, are you sure your `if request.method == POST` code is called? Can you set a breakpoint inside the if and check you reach that point?

Comment: You should add the `Task` model as well

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the create_task view:

```
  if request.method == 'POST':
            form = CreateTaskForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                # if you have user in your model task make commit to false then set the user
                form.save(commit=false)
                form.user = request.user
                #if not save directly you form
                form.save()
                return redirect('index')
```

then check if your url is:

```
path('create_task', create_task, name="create_task")
```

Comment: `form.user` is not part of the form and they did not share the model... how do you know that `user` is part of the model?

Comment: the problem is with his instance=request.user you don't need to add it. I added the form.user to set the user if it existe in your model as a foreignkey

Comment: True that ‘instance=request.user’ is not valid but adding ‘form.user’ without knowing is equally problematic

Comment: Yes but if the task model does not contain a 'user foreignkey' don't use 'form.user' save your form directly 'form.save()'.

Comment: Can you add your model.py?

Comment: You need to also return errors to the form as well... otherwise they will never be aware of validation issues

Comment: sure you need to add validations but in your forms.py not in your views.py.

Comment: Since it is a `ModelForm` the validation is based on the model, not the `forms.py` or the `views.py` - and you still have to output the euros back to the template.

Comment: Yes,but you can also add your custom validation. please can you edit your post and add your models.py.

Comment: Why would you want to do that when the model validation already does it for you? then you will have to maintain two sets of validations... one in the model and one in the form... seems like a good way to make more hassle and create less maintainable code

Comment: for exemple I have a form and an email field on it, and I want to check and accept only email with ['gmail', 'yahoo'], to do that I need to make a custom validation to handle it.

Comment: yes, and you can add that custom validator to you model - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/validators/

Comment: Yes, so we learn together :). and do you still get the form that is not saving to the datebase?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190552/discussion-between-incognos-and-idirall22).

Answer (score 0):

First off, since you are using `POST`, which means you are creating, there is no need for `instance=request.user` - which is used to compare previous data against new data provided by the form. Looking at your form, it does not look like it has anything to do with the user.

Second, you are not displaying or returning form errors. So it may be silently failing validation at the model level without your knowledge. Try adding a return with form errors.

```
@login_required
def create_task(request):
    form = CreateTaskForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateTaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('index')
     context = {'form': form}
     return render(request, 'tasks/task_form.html', context)
```

You can look in `form.errors` on the template side to see validation errors.